# I thought my solution for No. 1526 problem in LeetCode is decent but time exceeded

Tags: python, recursion, iteration

I am struggling to solve a hard problem ([No. 1526](https://leetcode.com/problems/minimum-number-of-increments-on-subarrays-to-form-a-target-array/)) in LeetCode but only to fail since my codes are rejected again and again by 'time exceeded'.

## Short Introduction to the No. 1526 Problem

[image]

The image below contains how I planned to solve the problem. Sorry for the bad resolution of it tho.

[image]

After I came up with this idea, I thought and still think it's a decent idea so I coded in two ways - recursive one and iterative one.

### Recursive

```py
target = [1, 2, 3, 2, 1]
score = 0

def minSubtract(target):
  global score
  if list(set(target)) == set([0]):
    return

  print(f"current arryay is {target}")
  localMin = min(target)
  score += localMin

  newTargets = [ele - localMin for ele in target]


  idx = 0
  Arr = []

  while idx < len(newTargets):
    print(idx)
    if newTargets[idx] != 0: # if nonzero element
      
      subArr = [newTargets[idx]]
      idx_ = idx + 1
      
      while True:

        if (idx_ >= len(newTargets) or (newTargets[idx_] == 0) ):
          idx = idx_
          Arr.append(subArr)
          break
        subArr.append(newTargets[idx_])
        idx_ += 1

    else:
      idx += 1

  print(f"subarrays are {Arr}")

  for subArray in Arr:
    minSubtract(subArray)
  
minSubtract(target)
score
```

### Iterative

```py
score = 0
stack = [target]


while stack:
  curArr = stack.pop()
  localMin = min(curArr)

  if localMin == 0:
    pass

  score += localMin
  SubtractedArr = [ele - localMin for ele in curArr]


  idx = 0
  Arrs = []
  while idx < len(SubtractedArr):

    if SubtractedArr[idx] != 0: # if nonzero element
      
      subArr = [SubtractedArr[idx]]
      idx_ = idx + 1
      
      while True:

        if (idx_ >= len(SubtractedArr) or (SubtractedArr[idx_] == 0) ):
          idx = idx_
          Arrs.append(subArr)
          break
        subArr.append(SubtractedArr[idx_])
        idx_ += 1

    else:
      idx += 1

  for newArr in Arrs:
    stack.append(newArr)

score
```

However, they both pass 126/128 test cases but still have a runtime issue. I want to know what makes my code have so bad speed or if actually by idea itself sucks.

Comment: What do the failing test cases complain about?

Comment: @dosas The only problem I got in solving it is 'time exceeding'. Especially for the target whose length is 8000 (127th test case in submission)

Comment: Since we have no idea what LeetCode Problem #1526 is, nor do we have the time to look it up, Please explain the problem and provide sample data and expected results we can use to test against.

Comment: @itprorh66 I've just updated my post! I am really sorry for my ignorance :(

Comment: There seems to be some problem with your iterative approach: `curArr = stack.pop()` will always yield an int so the following call to `min(curArr)` will raise a `TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable`> The next problem will occur when you try to loop ove `curArr` which cannot be done since it is an int.

Comment: Have you tried running/debugging your code locally?

Comment: @dosas Sorry but I don't think so, since my code works well for almost all test cases. You can check it if you set target as [3,1,5,4,2] and add the line ```print(curArr)``` right after popping for an example.

Comment: There is a very simple solution in O(n) - just one pass over the data. Take the values one by one, and see how many increments would have been needed to reach this value. Then consider the next one, and see if you would have needed more, or if you could have reached it as part of a previous increment. Less than 10 lines of code, and tested as working on LeetCode ;)